# Interesting Questions in Spectral Graph Theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

In the past, I have worked on few problems in Spectral graph theory and their applications to Physics. I have read parts of Fan Chung's book and Daniel Spielman lecture notes. I really enjoyed the topic and would like to explore it further. Can someone suggest interesting question or open problems?

Comment: Here is a list of a few open problems to start with: http://www.openproblemgarden.org/category/algebraical_graph_theory

Comment: And one list by Chris Godsil from 1995, I assume many of them are solved by now: http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/v2i1f1/pdf

Comment: and finally a list maintained by Peter J. Cameron: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/oldprob.html Not necessarily all of algebraic flavor.

Comment: Thanks for the useful links.