# How to find a research question and relevant materials

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, algebraic-graph-theory, online-resources, research

I am a PhD student working in Spectral Graph Theory.

Can anyone please help me solve the following questions:

1. How to find a research question?I contacted my advisor,he says he does not know how to find one as he has not read anything about the subject.Asked me to look at recent papers.
2. Where should I look for research materials?
   I read books on Spectral Graph Theory and solved questions at the back on my own but how to find research materials?

My advisor is involved in administrative matters and he does not seem interested at my research at all.Recently I found he is applying to other Universities for higher pay also.

Can someone please suggest something ?

Is there any website which gives research questions?Where do people find research questions?

Comment: You need to find a new supervisor ... now!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown; i want to and tried, i fear that if i leave him,he may make my life difficult

Comment: Don't be afraid of your supervisor. The one thing he should do before even taking on a PhD student is having a topic for the student. In perfect situations, the supervisor more or less knows the results and proof strategies you should be using. You are more than in your right to complain about this, he's wasting your time. Having said that, I have been (or still am) in a similar situation. I started talking to other people in the field and figured out some interesting topics and started asking the right questions. I'm now collaborating with active researchers and we have material coming up!

Comment: Whatever you decide, don't stay in such a situation for too long. It is very depressing and might even damage your mental well-being. Actively search for other people that can help you. Try to read as much about your field as well, you will train pure mathematical skills and get an overview of what is happening/interesting/difficult/unsolvable and doable.

Comment: @Mathematician42; I even asked him that I want to go to some professors in other universities,he refused

Comment: @Mathematician42;can you please share how you collaborated with researchers,I am really frustrated now,its been 2 and a half years

Comment: I often go to talks at other universities, talk to other PhD students in the field and try to get a grip on why certain topics are being investigated. One lucky day, I noticed that the work of some other student was somewhat incomplete and tried to fill in some gaps. When doing so a complete new theory emerged and a more experienced colleague and I decided to work out this new theory.

Comment: @PureMathematics you advisor does not own you. You are not contractually bound to an advisor in any way. If that advisor cannot suit your research efforts, find another professor who can.

Comment: This is perhaps a suitable Question for Academia.SE, but in the sense that resolving a problem with an adviser cannot be resolved by reasoned mathematical argument, this is mostly off-topic for Math.SE.  The one element that could be on-topic here would be to ask about open problems in Spectral Graph Theory.  My impression is that tagging such a Question as "big-list" and "reference-request" would allow Readers to help identify suitable research level topics.

Comment: Related: [Interesting Questions in Spectral Graph Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739422/interesting-questions-in-spectral-graph-theory)